# ProFTPd server fails to send directory listing

Tags: cygwin, ftp, proftpd

I host a FTP server with proftpd on Cygwin/Windows 7. Unfortunately it does not work, as people can log in, but not view the directory listing.
Cygwin users have guaranteed me this is a software issue and not a Cygwin issue, although I have no idea where to find the problem?

```
Filezilla:
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (22,200,19,128,211,145).
Command:    LIST
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing

/var/log/proftpd:
Homecomputer (144.24.42.183[144.24.42.183]) - FTP session opened.
Homecomputer (144.24.42.183[144.24.42.183]) - PRIVS_USER: unable to seteuid(session.login_uid): Invalid argument
Homecomputer (144.24.42.183[144.24.42.183]) - USER chronoz: Login successful.
Homecomputer (144.24.42.183[144.24.42.183]) - error: /var/log is a world writeable directory
Homecomputer (144.24.42.183[144.24.42.183]) - PRIVS_USER: unable to seteuid(session.login_uid): Invalid argument
Homecomputer (144.24.42.183[144.24.42.183]) - PRIVS_SETUP: unable to seteuid(): Invalid argument
Homecomputer (144.24.42.183[144.24.42.183]) - PRIVS_RELINQUISH: unable to seteuid(session.uid): Invalid argument
Homecomputer (144.24.42.183[144.24.42.183]) - PRIVS_RELINQUISH: unable to seteuid(session.uid): Invalid argument
```

Apache works perfectly fine in hosting the files and Google does not help me much in finding the cause.